# kafka connect kinessis connector fail to start

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, amazon-kinesis

we try to use the confluent kinessis-source connector for kafka connector (kafka cluster is confluent, kafka-connect deployed on k8s)
we use the trial - no license added yet,
we get the following error:

**org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: License topic could not be created**

```
WorkerConnector{id=kinessis-connector} Error while starting connectorsg","THREAD":"connector-thread-kinessis-for-connector","SRC":"org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: License topic could not be created
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Call(callName=createTopics, deadlineMs=1626952177722, tries=1, nextAllowedTryMs=1626952177823) timed out at 1626952177723 after 1 attempt(s)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createTopics
[Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=kafkaconnect-platform-dev] Failed to start connector 'kinessis-connector","SRC":"org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder"}
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to start connector: kinessis-connector
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.lambda$startConnector$5(DistributedHerder.java:1305)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doTransitionTo(WorkerConnector.java:335)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.doRun(WorkerConnector.java:140)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector.run(WorkerConnector.java:117)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

the connector configuration is:

````
{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.kinesis.KinesisSourceConnector",
  "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "*****.eu-west-1.aws.confluent.cloud:9092",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "kinesis.region": "eu-west-1",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "name": "kinessis-connector",
  "kafka.topic": "kinessis_events",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "kinesis.stream": "kinessis-events",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
}```
````

Comment: Create the license topic manually - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/license.html#configure-component-licenses

Comment: well, I tried, it doesn't helped, got the same error

Comment: Well, `License topic could not be created` is self-explanatory... Otherwise, `TimeoutException` means you have a network and/or authentication issue against Confluent Cloud

Comment: Have you checked that you set all the properties as described in https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-kinesis/current/kinesis_source_connector_config.html?